# a problem with Pointer to Pointer(AnyType **var) in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

As you know there is a generic class List in .NET framework.
I want to write a generic class List in C++ and i want to store pointers to a type in my list. this is header and source code of class and test program :

```
// header
template <class Type>
class List
{
public:
   List(int size);  // constructor
    .
    .
    . // other public members
private:
   Type **list; // a dynamic array of pointer to Type
    .
    .
    . // other private members 
};

// source code 
template <class Type> List<Type>::List(int size) // constructor
{
   this->list = new Type[size];
    .
    . // other parts of definition
}

// main function
void main()
{
    List<AnyType> mylist = new List<AnyType>(4);
    mylist[0] = new AnyType( // any arguments);
}
```

it does not work propertly. where is problem ? is it possible to use this class for Structs ?

Comment: It should be. However you need to tell us what you're expecting and what is happening

Comment: No, "a dynamic array of pointer to Type" would be `std::vector<Type *>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this->list = new Type[size];` should be `this->list = new Type*[size];`

Edit: did it actually compile? The assignment should at least generate a warning.

Comment: @Hesam Well, then the question should be "what is wrong with this code", but "what does this error mean" :)

Answer (score 1):

I see at least two problems:

- If you want to allocate an array of pointers to `Type` objects you have to substitute `new Type[size];` with `new Type*[size];`
- To use this syntax `mylist[0] = new AnyType(/* ... */)` you have to overload operator[] in your class

In general, C++ has a quite nice Standard Template Library that already contains implemenentations of generic lists ( `std::list` ) and arrays ( `std::vector` ).
See for instance [this reference](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
new Type[size];
```

to:

```
new Type*[size];
```

You want an array of pointers not an array of `Type`

Also what's wrong with `std::vector<Type*>`?

Answer (score 0):

myList is not an array, it contains an array. So either the type needs to have [] type operators (not sure if that's possible in C++) or a method that allows you to set the 
this->list[n] = some thing.

Simillar to this:

```
template <class Type> List<Type>::SetItem(int itemNumber, Type theItem ) 
{
   this->list[itemNum] = theItem;
}
```

and then call

```
myList.SetItem(0, new AnyType(...));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems in your code :

- The line `this->list = new Type[size];` allocates an array of `Type`, not an array of `Type *` : you might want to change this to `new Type*[size]`
- The code `List<AnyType> mylist = new List<AnyType>(4);` will not compile. Either use `List<AnyType> mylist(4);` or `List<AnyType> *mylist = new List<AnyType>(4);` (which would require an additional `delete` before exiting the program)
- I see you separated the implementation in a source file : I recommend you read [this item](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.12)

I'm skipping on the usual 'why would anyone develop his own list ?' and 'it looks more like a vector than like a list ?'.